# Splitting list with a specific "marker"

Tags: list, split, prolog

I had to create a predicate which splits a list at a specific point into smaller lists.

E.g. it has to part the following list [4,5,0,3,2,0,6,1] where the zero is.
Prolog's answer should be:

```
X=[[4,5],[3,2],[6,1]].
```

My solution (that actually works!) is the following:

```
get_chunk(_,[],[],[]). 
get_chunk(Splitter,[Splitter|L],[],L). 
get_chunk(Splitter,[Head|L],[Head|X],R) :- get_chunk(Splitter,L,X,R).  

split([],_,[]). 
split(SL,Splitter, [U|Us]) :- get_chunk(Splitter,SL,U,L), 
                              split(L,Splitter,Us).
```

Is there maybe an alternative solution, which is more elegant?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
split(I, S, [L|Cs]) :-
   append(L, [S|T], I) -> split(T, S, Cs) ; [L|Cs] = [I].
```

Comment: split([1,2],2,L). yields L=[[1],[]]. expected?

Comment: of course. Otherwise how do you know the list end with a separator ? Usually there is an option to change this behaviour, and get rid of empties.

Comment: ah I understand now :) I tried to get rid of it in my solution thought of it as excess :)

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a go and here is what I came up with :)

```
split([],Spliter,[]) :- !.
split(List,Spliter,[List]) :- not(member(Spliter,List)).
split(List,Spliter,[X|Ss]) :- append(X,[Spliter|Y],List),!,
                              split(Y,Spliter,Ss).
```